# wget for HTTPS website from dedicated server

Tags: curl, https, search-engine, wget

I recently migrated from a HTTP website to HTTPS. In order to index all pages of this website with `mnogosearch` search engine, I need to execute a script included into mnogosearch called "indexer" which actually fetch all pages of the webite and index them into a MySQL table.

This "indexer" script must be called from the machine hosting the HTTP server, i.e from the virtual private server (VPS).

This script worked very well with HTTP version of my website but I have issue with HTTPS indexing.

Indeed, to be able to index HTTPS pages, I use `"virtual scheme as an external retrieval system"` from this link : [http://www.mnogosearch.org/doc/msearch-extended-indexing.html][1]

It allows to use an external program to get the content of HTTPS page.

It works putting the external program into a script called `"curl.sh"` :

```
#!/bin/sh
wget -r --no-check-certificate $1
```

The problem is this "`wget -r --no-check-certificate https://example.com/`" command works from my local machine (it downloads all pages of my website "example.com") but it doesn't work when I launch it directly from my VPS where my HTTPS server is hosted (i.e example.com).

In the second case, it only downloads index.html.

Here's what I get when I do a recursive wget on the hosting machine :

```
$ wget -r --no-check-certificate https://example.com/
--2015-09-06 22:22:12--  https://example.com/
Résolution de example.com (example.com)... 
Connexion vers example.com (example.com)...connecté.
Le propriétaire du certificat ne concorde pas avec le nom de l'hôte «example.com»
requête HTTP transmise, en attente de la réponse...200 OK
Longueur: 177 [text/html]a
Sauvegarde en : «example.com/index.html»

100%[========================================================================================================================================>] 177         --.-K/s   ds 0s      

2015-09-06 22:22:12 (5,08 MB/s) - «example.com/index.html» sauvegardé [177/177]

FINISHED --2015-09-06 22:22:12--
Total wall clock time: 0,5s
Downloaded: 1 files, 177 in 0s (5,08 MB/s)
```

and the index.html is not valid, here's its content :

```
<html><body><h1>It works!</h1>
<p>This is the default web page for this server.</p>
<p>The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet.</p>
</body></html>
```

I make you notice that my HTTPS server is accessible on 8443 port (I did a rewrite rule that redirects HTTPS 443 request to 8443 port).

So I tried also :

```
wget -r --no-check-certificate https://example.com:8443/
```

In this case, wget attempts apparently to fetch all pages but I have a 404 eror fro each page :

```
$ wget -r --no-check-certificate https://example.com:8443/
--2015-09-06 22:39:03--  https://example.com:8443/
Résolution de example.com (example.com)... 
Connexion vers example.com (example.com)||:8443...connecté.
requête HTTP transmise, en attente de la réponse...303 See Other
Emplacement: index.html [suivant]
--2015-09-06 22:39:04--  https://example.com:8443/index.html
Réutilisation de la connexion existante vers example.com:8443.
requête HTTP transmise, en attente de la réponse...200 OK
Longueur: 7389 (7,2K) [text/html]
Sauvegarde en : «example.com:8443/index.html»

100%[========================================================================================================================================>] 7 389       --.-K/s   ds 0s      

2015-09-06 22:39:04 (145 MB/s) - «example.com:8443/index.html» sauvegardé [7389/7389]

Chargement de robots.txt; svp ignorer les erreurs.
--2015-09-06 22:39:04--  https://example.com:8443/robots.txt
Réutilisation de la connexion existante vers example.com:8443.
requête HTTP transmise, en attente de la réponse...200 OK
Longueur: 138 [text/plain]
Sauvegarde en : «example.com:8443/robots.txt»

100%[========================================================================================================================================>] 138         --.-K/s
```

**UPDATE** : I have forgotten to say that I have a Twisted python server behind Apache and this Twisted server is listenning on port 8443, that's why I have done a redirection from 443 to 8443 port

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to the server, the simplest solution might be to change your Apache configuration so that port 443 goes to the same host/virtualhost as port 8443. Then, if you try to download https://example.com/ on the server again, all of your absolute links using https://example.com/ will work as well, and you'll be able to download everything via the normal port.

Further down the road, I think you may want to drop the `-r` flag and add `-S -O -` to your wget command line, . It looks like the software you're using expects the headers and body of the server's response to be output on the console, not saved to a file.

Comment: What do you mean by changing Apache configuration so that port 443 goes the same host/virtualhost  as port 8443 ? I have already the following rewrite rule : RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L] and the following iptables rule : -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8443 . What can I do more ?

Comment: First of all, the iptables rule doesn't help you when you're on the same machine, it only applies to incoming traffic from other clients. ([source](http://askubuntu.com/a/595955/435294)) Thus, when you run wget on your server, it connects to Apache on port 443, skipping the iptables rule. The "real" site is only set up to respond on port 8443 currently. If you change your <VirtualHosts> directive to handle both ports 443 and 8443, that would fix the issue.

Another solution: see the iptables post linked above, you could add another iptables rule to the OUTPUT chain to redirect the port locally